# Prove the following set is infinite (for all epsilon greater than 0)

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have a fixed, bounded infinite sequence$\ (b_{n}) \ $and for each$\ n\in\mathbb{N}^{+}, \ $we set$\ w_{n} \ =inf\{b_{n},b_{n+1},b_{n+2},...\} \ $and$\ g_{n} \ =sup\{b_{n},b_{n+1},b_{n+2},...\}. \ $We also let$\ g=inf\{g_{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}^{+}\} \ $and$\ w=sup\{w_{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}^{+}\}. \ $Prove that$\ \forall\epsilon>0, \ $the set$\ \{n\in\mathbb{N}^{+}:b_{n}>g-\epsilon\} \ $is infinite.

A proof by contradiction perhaps?

My understanding:

If $\ g \ $is the *greatest lower bound* for$\ g_{n}\ $then$\ g-\epsilon \ $(for any$\ \epsilon>0) \ $is certainly a lower bound for$\ g_{n}.\ $As we know, the supremum/infimum is not required to belong to a set (if it does though, its called the maximum/minimum of the set), but whether it belongs to or doesn't belong to the set isn't significant here: what we know for certain is anything greater than the supremum of a set must be strictly greater than every element of the set. Likewise, anything less than the infimum of a set must be strictly less than every element of the set. With this in mind, it's pretty clear that the set$\ \{n\in\mathbb{N}^{+}:g_{n}>g-\epsilon\} \ $is infinite - there are infinitely many $\ n's \ $(in $\mathbb{N}^{+})\ $which satisfy$\ g_{n}>g-\epsilon \ $, in fact, every$\ n\in\mathbb{N}^{+}\ $would satisfy$\ g_{n}>g-\epsilon, \ $therefore$\ g_{1}>g-\epsilon, \ $but$\ g_{1} \ $is the supremum of the set$\ \{b_{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}^{+}\}, \ $which describes the infinite sequence$\ (b_{n}) \ $and therefore...I don't really know where to go from here or whether I'm even going in the right direction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the sequence $\{g_n\}$ is non-increasing (we are taking the supremum of less numbers). Hence $g_n\ge g$ for all $n$.
Let $N\in\Bbb N$ be given. By the supremum-property of $g_N$, there exists $n\ge N$ such that $b_n>g_N-\epsilon$. Then also $b_n>g_N-\epsilon\ge g-\epsilon$.
Thus for all $N$, there exists $n\ge N$ with $b_n>g-\epsilon$, i.e., the set of such $n$ is infinite.